# Cocos2d-x: Triangle painting code using OpenGL ES2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, draw, paint, cocos2d-x

Dye can come out of a rectangle is cocos2d-x each rewrite draw will appear by default rectangles, Mody?

Code download From  Thanks in advance.

http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=1687059334&uk=3238029663

Comment: Don't hide essential information of your question behind a link. The page you linked to will go away and your question will become useless. Shorten code to a comfortable length (but keep in mind that it should be self contained) and insert it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=1687059334&uk=3238029663

code download  code download  code downloadcode downloadcode downloadcode downloadcode download